# How do i display retrofit results in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, retrofit

How do i display retrofit results in `RecycerView` ? sorry for the noob question. Thanks for reading this

UPDATE:

After creating a retrofit Restclient and setting up the recyclerview, I get this error, below i will include my logcat along with the project on github.

Project: https://github.com/nyamwaya/JunitTesting
Logcat: Its in the readme.md of the above git hub project(Stack was giving me a hard time posting code on here. sorry for any inconveniences)

If you figure it out, please explain to me where the problem was and how you fixed it and why it happened.

Comment: This question needs to have an example of the result you are asking to use.